# Bugs in example of Android bluetooth connection between devices

Tags: android, debugging, bluetooth

I'm trying to learn some Android programming.
I started with small bluetooth project which has starting point from the bluetooth example taken from [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-bluetooth-connection-example/)
The example is great and running fine at first. However, as I use the app more frequently, I cannot make successful bluetooth connection between devices anymore.

I have one tablet and one smartphone. I use them to test the connection. At first, both are successfully connected. However, after few times, I cannot connect those device. When I click the connect button and choose the other device, nothing happens, it just like waiting for something. I don't know, I try by keep clicking the connect but nothing happens, even the Toast of unable to connect does not turn on.

I suspect there is something wrong with the code, I tried to compare it with other sample code online but I failed to notice what cause such mystery bug.

Can anybody help me with this case please?

---

I update with logcat
The lines marked with star

> 07-08 22:44:37.001 626-754/? E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
>   07-08 22:44:37.387 6193-6193/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
>   07-08 22:44:37.558 6193-6193/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
>   07-08 22:44:37.558 6193-6193/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
>   07-08 22:44:38.214 6209-6209/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
>   07-08 22:44:38.385 6209-6209/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
>   07-08 22:44:38.385 6209-6209/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
>   07-08 22:44:38.690 626-948/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
>   07-08 22:44:39.666 28798-28798/? E/ydp: checkApp pkgName:com.javacodegeeks
>   07-08 22:44:40.391 626-948/? E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
>   07-08 22:44:40.534 626-906/? E/IBINDER_HOOK_UTILS: ===================hook request type:24
>   07-08 22:44:40.544 626-945/? E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
>   07-08 22:44:40.565 626-906/? E/IBINDER_HOOK_UTILS: safecenter block 0
>   07-08 22:44:40.566 626-637/? E/IBINDER_HOOK_SYSTEM: get last known location
>   07-08 22:44:40.566 626-637/? E/IBINDER_HOOK_UTILS: ===================hook request type:37
>   07-08 22:44:40.591 626-637/? E/IBINDER_HOOK_UTILS: safecenter block 0
>   07-08 22:44:40.600 626-949/? E/IBINDER_HOOK_SYSTEM: get last known location
>   07-08 22:44:40.600 626-949/? E/IBINDER_HOOK_UTILS: ===================hook request type:37
>   07-08 22:44:40.619 626-949/? E/IBINDER_HOOK_UTILS: safecenter block 0
>   07-08 22:44:40.623 626-945/? E/IBINDER_HOOK_SYSTEM: request location updata
>   07-08 22:44:40.623 626-945/? E/IBINDER_HOOK_UTILS: ===================hook request type:22
>   07-08 22:44:40.624 626-907/? E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
>   07-08 22:44:40.648 626-945/? E/IBINDER_HOOK_UTILS: safecenter block 0
>   07-08 22:44:40.659 626-906/? E/IBINDER_HOOK_SYSTEM: request location updata
>   07-08 22:44:40.659 626-906/? E/IBINDER_HOOK_UTILS: ===================hook request type:22
>   07-08 22:44:40.675 626-906/? E/IBINDER_HOOK_UTILS: safecenter block 0
>   07-08 22:44:40.707 626-2751/? E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
>   07-08 22:44:40.745 626-906/? E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
>   07-08 22:44:40.884 626-2747/? E/IBINDER_HOOK_UTILS: ===================hook request type:43
>   07-08 22:44:40.893 626-2747/? E/IBINDER_HOOK_UTILS: safecenter block 0
>   07-08 22:44:40.921 31013-31029/? E/BluetoothServiceJni: SOCK FLAG = 3 ***********************
>                                                           [ 07-08 22:44:40.921 31013:0x7935 I/         ]
>                                                           [JSR82][JBT] JBT jbt_session_service_registration
>   07-08 22:44:40.921 31013-31113/? E/MTKBT: [Session]the session[61440][31013] is not ready to monitor
>   07-08 22:44:40.921 31013-31113/? E/MTKBT: [Session]the session[61442][31013] is not ready to monitor
>   07-08 22:44:40.921 31013-31113/? E/MTKBT: [Session]the session[61460][31013] is not ready to monitor
>   07-08 22:44:40.921 31013-31113/? E/MTKBT: [Session]no any more session is in list
>   07-08 22:44:40.921 31013-31113/? E/MTKBT: [Session]the session[61440][31013] is not ready to monitor
>   07-08 22:44:40.921 31013-31113/? E/MTKBT: [Session]the session[61442][31013] is not ready to monitor
>   07-08 22:44:40.921 31013-31113/? E/MTKBT: [Session]the session[61460][31013] is not ready to monitor
>   07-08 22:44:40.921 31013-31113/? E/MTKBT: [Session]no any more session is in list
>   07-08 22:44:41.408 626-626/? E/RemoteViews: ANR Warning,RemoteViews can only be used once ,if not ,it may cause ANR in hosts such as Laucher,SystemUI. keys for search 
>   07-08 22:44:41.408 626-626/? E/RemoteViews: ANR Warning,RemoteViews can only be used once ,if not ,it may cause ANR in hosts such as Laucher,SystemUI. keys for search 
>   07-08 22:44:41.617 626-626/? E/RemoteViews: ANR Warning,RemoteViews can only be used once ,if not ,it may cause ANR in hosts such as Laucher,SystemUI. keys for search 
>   07-08 22:44:41.618 626-626/? E/RemoteViews: ANR Warning,RemoteViews can only be used once ,if not ,it may cause ANR in hosts such as Laucher,SystemUI. keys for search 
>   07-08 22:45:00.065 19822-19822/? E/ActionIcon: time changed: time = 20170708T224500Asia/Saigon(6,188,25200,0,1499528700)
>   07-08 22:45:00.080 626-948/? E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
>   07-08 22:45:19.590 837-1173/? E/CellLocation: create GsmCellLocation
>   07-08 22:45:19.600 837-1173/? E/CellLocation: create GsmCellLocation
>   07-08 22:45:20.422 626-2747/? E/IBINDER_HOOK_SYSTEM: get wifimanager getscanresults
>   07-08 22:45:28.690 626-947/? E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
>   07-08 22:45:30.723 31013-31029/? E/BTIF_CORE: [btmtk_gap_cancel_discovery] failed!
>   07-08 22:45:37.093 31013-31023/? E/BTIF_CORE: [btmtk_gap_cancel_discovery] failed!
>   07-08 22:45:40.770 626-949/? E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
>   07-08 22:45:40.876 626-944/? E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
>   07-08 22:45:41.031 626-907/? E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
>   07-08 22:45:41.646 626-637/? E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
>   07-08 22:45:41.881 626-2747/? E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
>   07-08 22:45:42.107 837-6898/? E/ctxmgr: [ProducerActiveIntervalImpl]closeExistingAppInterval: does not exist
>   07-08 22:45:42.108 837-6898/? E/ctxmgr: [ProducerActiveIntervalImpl]closeActiveInterval: Error: ongoing, trying to close
>   07-08 22:45:42.109 837-6898/? E/ctxmgr: [ProducerActiveIntervalImpl]closeExistingAppInterval: does not exist
>   07-08 22:45:42.111 837-6898/? E/ctxmgr: [ProducerActiveIntervalImpl]closeActiveInterval: Error: ongoing, trying to close
>   07-08 22:45:42.113 837-6898/? E/ctxmgr: [ProducerActiveIntervalImpl]closeExistingAppInterval: does not exist
>   07-08 22:45:42.116 837-6898/? E/ctxmgr: [ProducerActiveIntervalImpl]closeActiveInterval: Error: ongoing, trying to close
>   07-08 22:46:00.052 19822-19822/? E/ActionIcon: time changed: time = 20170708T224600Asia/Saigon(6,188,25200,0,1499528760)
>   07-08 22:46:00.068 626-907/? E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
>   07-08 22:46:00.571 626-2747/? E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
>   07-08 22:46:02.089 31013-31023/? E/BTIF_CORE: [btmtk_gap_cancel_discovery] failed!
>   07-08 22:46:03.056 31013-31028/? E/BTIF_CORE: [btmtk_gap_cancel_discovery] failed!
>   07-08 22:46:09.460 626-754/? E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
>   07-08 22:46:10.788 31013-31028/? E/BTIF_CORE: [btmtk_gap_cancel_discovery] failed!
>   07-08 22:46:11.757 31013-31024/? E/BTIF_CORE: [btmtk_gap_cancel_discovery] failed!
>   07-08 22:46:19.784 626-946/? E/IBINDER_HOOK_SYSTEM: get last known location
>   07-08 22:46:19.806 837-1173/? E/CellLocation: create GsmCellLocation
>   07-08 22:46:19.823 837-1173/? E/CellLocation: create GsmCellLocation
>   07-08 22:46:20.510 626-947/? E/IBINDER_HOOK_SYSTEM: get wifimanager getscanresults
>   07-08 22:46:20.594 626-636/? E/IBINDER_HOOK_SYSTEM: get wifimanager getscanresults

Comment: I updated with logcat. I noticed the lines 07-08 22:46:02.089 31013-31023/? E/BTIF_CORE: [btmtk_gap_cancel_discovery] failed!
07-08 22:46:03.056 31013-31028/? E/BTIF_CORE: [btmtk_gap_cancel_discovery] failed!
is printed out when I click on paired device to connect to.